# SQL Developer cant find my oracle vm

Tags: java, oracle, bash

1. I just installed oracle 12c on my oracle vm but cant connect to it
2. through sql developer from my windows. I can ping it on windows `cmd`

   and it returns without loosing package. My bash profile has a
   different sid than the default oracl sid orcl. After creation of my
   db, I had to recreate the spfile because I couldn't open the database.

   Here's my bash profile:

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracle12C.localdomain
   export ORACLE_UNQNAME=db1
   export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle
   export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0/db_1
   export ORACLE_SID=db1

   export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
   export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
   export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
   ```

   Heres my listener

   ```
   LISTENER =


   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
       (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12C.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
       )
     )
   ```

   After creation of my db, I had to recreate the spfile because I couldn't open database.

Please help me someone.

Comment: Hi, did you check firewall settings? Port 1521 should be reachable from outside.

Comment: the linux 7 i installed didnt come with a firewall.I can ping the ip from a windows cmd,so i think the linux firewall is not really the issue here.